# Multi-GPU passthrough to Windows 10 VM fails before booting

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, kvm, pci-passthrough

I've successfully set up Windows 10 VM with 5 x Nvidia 1080Ti cards passed through, using kvm, libvirt, virt-manager and vfio-pci on Ubuntu 16.04. All working fine. If I attempt to passthrough more than 5 GPUs, the VM freezes before booting, this means that I'm not even able to reach the windows boot-loader, there is brief spike on the CPU graph in virt-manager before it returns to idle.

So far:

- Using a *i440FX* chipset only enabled passthrough of 3 GPUs, using a *q35* chipset enabled up to 5.

I have a Ubuntu VM working with more than 5 GPUs passed through, so I assume the problem is related to the virtualisation of Windows.

What could be the limiting factor that only allows for a certain amount of cards to be passed through?